# Do a gradle task that tests, do connectedAndroidTest, builds and executes a script in GRADLE

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've got a Gradle project, right now I can:

```
test it                         : rootdir$gradle test
build it                        : rootdir$gradle build
run android instrumental tests  : rootdir$gradle connectedAndroidTest
execute a script                : rootdir$gradle app:uploadArchives
```

I'd like to do a task that tests, do the connected android tests, build the apk and finally run the uploadArchives task.

I've placed this code into build.gradle:

```
task doAll(dependsOn: ['app:test','app:connectedAndroidTest','app:build','uploadArchives'])
```

but it doesn't works when I do

```
rootdir$gradle doAll
```

It says:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':doAll'.
>   Task with path 'app:test' not found in root project 'MyProj'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task doAll(dependsOn: ["build", "test", "connectedAndroidTest", "uploadArchives"]) { ... }
tasks.test.dependsOn(build)
tasks.connectedAndroidTest.dependsOn(test)
tasks.uploadArchives.dependsOn(connectedAndroidTest)
```

Comment: When I run this it appears the following failure message:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:doAll'.
> Task with path 'test' not found in project ':app'.

Comment: run "./gradlew tasks" and check if "test", "build", "connectedAndroidTest", "uploadArchives" exist. Gradle says that there is no "test" task, than you should have another tasks which runs tests. The main idea is in ".dependsOn()" instructions, here you specify which gradle tasks depends on another gradle task, read the gradle documentation for better understanding of ".dependsOn()".